# Mysql query for specific record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table which contains record of different status of books. A same book may have multiple records but each record have same unique id i.e bid like this

```
id     bookname      bid
------------------------
1      vb.net        681
2      html          682
3      vb.net        681
4      vb.net        681
5      html          682
```

I want to pick the last record of specific bid 681 or 682. Please help me to write a SQL query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns each bid's max id. Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select max(id) as maxid, bid
      from tablename
      group by bid) t2 on t1.id = t2.maxid
```

Comment: @jeroen, `JOIN` is just a short form of `INNER JOIN`, no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nice but returned an error for me with tablename but this worked fine:-

```
select t1.*
from t1
join (select max(id) as maxid, bid
      from t1
      group by bid) t2 on t1.id = t2.maxid
```

maybe different versions?